# What's the best way to wrap an Python for loop with unpacking?

Tags: python, coding-style

I had a for loop like so:

```
a = [[1,2]]
for (x, y in a):
    pass
```

Except the for loop was unpacking several values, and all the variable names were long and descriptive.

I wanted to wrap the line using perens which has always worked for me in python, but when I tried:

```
a = [[1,2]]
for (x, y in
        a):
    pass
```

I got a syntax error?

What is the best way to wrap long for loop lines which also do unpacking?

UPDATE:

I also tried:

```
for ((x, y)
        in a):
    pass
```

and got a syntax error.

Comment: Try `for (x, y) in a`. I can't experiment at the moment, but it should work.

Comment: As you can see in my update, that also gives a syntax error.

Comment: @Buttons840. Remove those outer parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (x,y in a):
```

is *itself* a syntax error. You can use

```
for (x,y) in a:
```

which can also span multiple lines as such:

```
>>> for (super_long_descriptive_name_1,
...      super_long_descriptive_name_2) in a:
...     pass
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error comes from putting `()` marks around your conditional, python does not need this.

Instead of this:

```
for (x, y in a):
  pass
```

try this:

```
for x, y in a:
  pass
```

You could, if you choose, wrap the tuple in parentheses for better readability

```
for (x, y) in a:
  pass
```

Comment: The question was about how to wrap long lines.

Comment: @Buttons840 I explained that you can't.  Python cuts out many unnecessary parentheses

Comment: Did you mean word wrap?  Like the text reflow off of the edge of the page? @Buttons840

Comment: Most of the time you can wrap text inside parenthesis in python.  I thought it was unusually that you can't do that with a for loop.